# Making Gmail Addon Accessible Without Clicking on Email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I have been trying to develop a Gmail Addon with Google Appsscript. Just like the calendar, I want my addon to be accessible without clicking on an email. To clarify, as soon as gmail opens, I want the addon to be visible. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: In my experience, no.  You have to open an email.

Comment: +Sebastian are you saying that there is a calendar addon that produces the intended behaviour? which addon is it?

Comment: Yes, the built in Calendar addon does show up even when you don't open an email

Answer (score 3):

Not currently possible. Non-google Add-ons only show for an open email.

> When the user opens a Gmail message that meets the trigger criteria* the trigger fires [and the Add-on runs].
>
> *Currently, the only contextual trigger type available is unconditional, which triggers for all emails regardless of content. ([src](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/building))